# What would an appropriate fourth title be in the set "page, squire, knight"?

Tags: single-word-requests

At work we have training levels for technical skills that are assessed by qualification tests. Currently there are three levels: page, squire, and knight. I need to add a new level, but from what I understand the path to Knighthood only has those three levels.

What word could be used as an appropriate additional skill level keeping this theme? It could be inserted at any location, before or after any of the three words.

Comment: _Lord_, or possibly some title of nobility, like _count_, or a military title, like _commander_ or _general_, depending on the particular backstory and the feudal system you're basing it on. Different places had different categories.

Comment: I'm guessing that despite your "any location" allowance, you're really not looking for "stable boy", "serf", "peasant", "lackey", or the like... :-)

Comment: . . . but if so, how about "guileless fool"? But I suppose Perceval had to *remain* that even as a knight (or paladin) in order to obtain the Grail.

Answer (score 3):

To continue with your medieval theme other options are in order of rank:

> Duke
>
> Viscount
>
> Baron
>
> *Knight*
>
> *Squire*
>
> Gentleman
>
> *Page*

This [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight) has many more higher ranking options.

Comment: A Viscount is superior to a baron,

Comment: @Martin - perhaps he's a discount viscount.

Comment: @Martin: well-spotted, I've updated the Viscount ranking; no longer discounted.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest *Paladin:* OED “a knight renowned for heroism and chivalry; a famous champion.” This is more a literary honorific than an official rank, but it has the advantage of suggesting a kind of superiority over the average knight, without implying *command authority* the way a superior feudal rank would do. I gather the term is fairly well established as a distinct rank or “[character class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paladin_%28character_class%29)” in the gaming world.

Answer (score 0):

Ranking immediately above a Knight (while still below true nobility) may be a *[Baronet](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/53794/baronet)*, though this position is not necessarily reached by way of Knighthood.

Comment: No it is not, nor did it exist before the seventeenth century.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Is it a problem that it didn't exist before the C17th?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think page-to-squire-to-knight as "path to Knighthood" (OP's term) was rather passé by then. The consensus seems to be that OP is going for some kind of medieval conceit.

Comment: @BrianDonovan, In the absence of technically-accurate options otherwise, I think that a little license is acceptable, no?